# Convert to date from an unusual format

Tags: r, date

I have date values in the format "February 20,2021". Can you suggest a way to convert this string to date? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `as.Date("February 20,2021", "%B %d,%Y")`

Comment: Function `mdy` from library `lubridate` will work too.

Comment: `library(anytime); anydate("February 20,2021")`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers!